# Is posting several "trivial" questions in bulk encouraged for the site? What’s the solution for it?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions, community, post-quality

**Summary:** a certain user is at large, spamming the site with trivial questions, the answers to which he is aware of, just for votes. Is such behaviour encouraged, if not what’s the solution?

---

**UPDATE 16/10/2021**- The same user is back with his incessant basic questions, with at least 2 identified usernames:

1. [Fun Life](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/25781/fun-life)
2. [User 23998](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/23998/user23998)
   He had previously deleted his account.
   Please give a solution.

**Detailed:**
Of late, there has been a [user](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/20919/abhiram-ekula) who had been answering many Mahabharata-related questions. He seems to have a fair insight about where (evident from his answers), to find the material on the sacred-texts site, in relation to the questions answered by him. However, he hadn’t received many votes, probably due to a lack of formatting that hampers readability, and used to make trivial edits to answers.
All of a sudden there has been an avalanche of trivial questions related to Mahabharata, the answers to which he seems to be aware of, having read quite a bit of the Sacred texts Mahabharata (as stated above). He may not have read the entire but he has a very fair idea, meaning he asks some (not all) questions for getting votes. It is evident from his comment to [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46583/were-the-100-kauravas-jarasandha-kamsa-shakuni-shishupala-and-other-kings-av) where he asks, about which asuras incarnated as Kaurava and others? In the answer below, it has been mentioned Karna is a portion of Narakasura, to which he replies:

> Karna is not incarnation of narakasura but he is a portion of surya – Abhiram Ekula 16 hours ago

This shows that he has a basic idea. When you know why you asking? This is not even knowledge sharing.

A few people have requested him to discontinue this. Examples of such questions are:

1. [What boon did Rishi Durvasa give to Kunti, the mother of Pandavas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46610/what-boon-did-rishi-durvasa-give-to-kunti-the-mother-of-pandavas)

> This is too much trivial. It's a duplicate already. Please just google search.

2. [Who is the guru of Bhishma, Drona, and Karna?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46605/who-is-the-guru-of-bhishma-drona-and-karna?noredirect=1#comment148026_46605)

> Please don’t ask questions and answers unnecessarily only for votes. We know you’ve read the entire sacred texts Mahabharata. It’s not worth the effort – Archit 12 hours ago

He deleted this particular one thereafter. Despite so many attempts he didn’t stop spamming the site.

Now proof of asking for the heck of it:

He asks [Who cursed the snakes that they will die in Emperor Janamejaya's snake sacrifice?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46598/who-cursed-the-snakes-that-they-will-die-in-emperor-janamejayas-snake-sacrifice) **about 15 hours ago**

After this he asks, [Which Kuru king of Pandava race performed the snake sacrifice where the Mahabharata was recited first by Vaisampayana?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46612/which-kuru-king-of-pandava-race-performed-the-snake-sacrifice-where-the-mahabhar) **about 10 hours ago**, i.e. after asking about Janamejaya’s snake sacrifice. He knew that Janamejaya performed snake sacrifice yet he asks who which Pandava descendent performed snake sacrifice, just for votes.

And the list goes on and on. As I have repeatedly stated:

> He knows where to find in the sacred text version. **He just wants votes and problem is he’s not getting** as many as he wants. He thinks by asking multiple questions he’ll get answers and at least he can get +2 +2 by accepting them or by chance questions may have a higher chance of being voted. – Archit 43 mins ago

**Question:** 
What is the solution to such behaviour which is not encouraged? There’s nothing the mods can do here.

Every question in such a long list can’t be monitored, irrelevant ones can’t be closed, can’t be flagged as low quality. I would personally find it mean to downvote him when he’s doing this whole drama to get points. Let this discussion apply to anyone else exhibiting similar behavior in the future too and not specifically this user.

Yet the site is being spammed and other good QnAs don’t get a chance to be seen by people, as they get lost amongst these kinds of "spam questions". Also, so many **unanswered questions bring the score of the site down and DELAYS GRADUATION.**

**EDIT:-**
Also another issue. On going to his profile one will see that he has deleted just a few minutes back, all questions which had net downvotes. All of a sudden reputation has shot up, without community voting. Very clever tactic?

**EDIT 2:**
 questions likely flagged as duplicates or downvoted are being converted to entirely new questions

Comment: A huge disadvantage of this incessant spamming is that several new questions and answers posts, which are good, are lost down the list and thus can't get enough "attention (views)".

Comment: Another problem is if those Q's are not answered or closed.. unanswered% will increase..I m not aware of any policy other than self answering which he is violating..May be we should flag such Q's so that mods can educate such users or take any action if they find some violation..

Comment: Please keep the user anonymous while discussing on meta. You can post links to the posts though.

Comment: Currently the interesting thing which is going on is, out of top 20 active questions, 16 questions are asked by him...

Comment: Nice information on the edit.

Comment: @Vivikta it seems he undeleted few again. Too much effort to update question again

Comment: @Vivikta woohoo!!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As others said in their answers, it is evident here that [user](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/20919/abhiram-ekula) is deliberately asking questions just for sake of reputation. If an user vandalizes site with low quality trivial questions, alert the system by **heavily downvoting** his posts as soon as he posts questions, so that he would [encounter question block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291142). This would also defy his purpose of getting easy rep. Heavily downvoted questions also don't appear of frontpage.

From above meta post:

> We believe asking questions on our site is a privilege, not a right. If, after a few fair attempts, you haven’t been able to prove that your contributions to Stack Overflow make it at least … not-worse … then we reserve the right to refuse your questions. If we don’t do our part to cull the bad questions, then we risk alienating the true experts who provide what really matters: the answers!

In these cases, community can solve this by voting. If there is no enough participation from community or user doesn't change after encountering question ban, then mods can intervene and either warn or ban him based on severity of issue.

Comment: Thank you moderator.

Comment: Does the user know that we are discussing his actions here?

Comment: The other answers suggesting to not vote even the good questions from this user, for some time being. Also to answer in comments. I am finding it hard to digest. Any thoughts?

Comment: Accepting this answer since it’s the highest voted by the community.

Answer (score 7):

Currently, the problem is becoming severe even more. Out of the top 20 active questions, 16 questions are already asked by him. One is allowed to ask the questions which one knows as one can self answer also. But asking these huge no. of questions in this short interval of time is certainly like spamming the site.

If one really wants to ask these questions, one should show patience and ask one or two questions daily so that site doesn't get flooded suddenly by a huge number of questions.

In the StackOverflow site, it is a common practice to heavily downvote questions when they do not show any research effort, we might as well do something like this. Doing this we achieve:

> - It stops one from asking questions just for sake of reputation.
> - The system automatically bans such users for a certain time from asking questions.

If this problem stops, then we can slowly edit the questions which we previously downvoted, and undownvote them or upvote them also.

There are some questions which are just asked for the sake of asking questions like:

> [If Kripacharya can be immortal, why Dronacharya was not offered the boon to be immortal?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46667/if-kripacharya-can-be-immortal-why-dronacharya-was-not-offered-the-boon-to-be-i)
>
> [What would happened to the earth in Kali Yuga if the Kurukshetra war did not happen and if people with divine weapons knowledge existed in Kali yuga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46654/what-would-happened-to-the-earth-in-kali-yuga-if-the-kurukshetra-war-did-not-hap)
>
> [What are the similarities of Ravana and Duryodhana besides being the villain of their epics?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46660/what-are-the-similarities-of-ravana-and-duryodhana-besides-being-the-villain-of)

Old users of HSE might remember that during the Saxena era also he asked lots of questions but he maintained a time interval between the questions and hence it didn't become like spamming.

Another thing we should stop doing for the time being is we should stop upvoting any questions (he asks) even if they are good until this problem gets solved. We might upvote them later if those questions deserved upvotes. Getting some upvotes in some of the questions might be encouraging him to ask more and more questions.

So here is what I suggest we should do:

> - Let's post the link of this meta question in the question he asks as a comment so that he knows what is going on.
> - Let's wait for the flood of another wave of questions and if the same behavior is repeated let's downvote questions. After his several questions are downvoted he will automatically be banned by the system from asking questions. We might remove our downvote from those questions later if the situation cools down and if they deserve.
> - We can both close and downvote hypothetical questions like the ones in the above example.
> - For the time being let's answer the user's trivial questions only in the comments so that the user can't think of accepting the answer and increasing reputation. We might post a real answer to the question after some days.

If doing these all also such types of behaviors aren't stopped then moderator intervention is a must. Moderators should save the site from being spammed.
We can apply similar methods like this for future users also who will flood the questions on the site. This is what I suggest and think we should do. Please give your views on this!

Comment: I don't agree with we should downvote even if the question is good and should answer in comments. Instead we should actively answer, flag/downvote/close if some are low quality. We should take this as challenge. If the answers are simple for good questions, let's just answer it. On a bright side, this will increase our answer rating.

Comment: @Green I explained why you can’t flag. Refer [comment](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2289/is-posting-several-trivial-questions-in-bulk-encouraged-for-the-site-what-s/2291#comment10761_2290). The answer is not saying to downvote good questions, he is saying to not upvote them. There are many users still upvoting some Qs, and he’s not upvoting their answers. Questions which deserve to be closed and downvoted will be closed as well as downvoted, not only closed. Green, you can start flagging and tell us how mods react to low quality flag.

Comment: @Archit if it is a good question, we should definitely upvote it. Not hold it as grudge against a particular user. This is unjust of what this site stands for. We just have to actively filter out but not take a path targeting a user. I will flag/close if it is low quality or upvote if it is a good question irrespective of any user.

Comment: @Green no one is holding it as a grudge. The answer itself is saying wait, vote later, after he stops spamming the site. This answer covers all your doubts. And I hope you won’t go against the community consensus of holding their votes for the time being. Even If you individually dont hold your votes here, other better deserving questions wouldn’t get votes and it’ll be holding a grudge against the community at large I.e. favouring spam questions by upvoting them and holding a grudge against all other community questions

Comment: And maybe you can start the challenge of answering. Let’s see whether he returns an upvote on your answer. (He’s not been doing that for other experienced members like YDS etc but tells them to vote for him)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, there is a question ban if the user is spamming with low-quality posts. We just have to actively flag/close/downvote for it to [automatically take care](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60294/196352) or mods attention.

[Link](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans)

> If a user cannot demonstrate, after asking a reasonable number of questions, that their contributions are making the site better (or at very least, not making it worse) then they will be blocked from asking further questions until they have demonstrated their ability to contribute positively.

Comment: So you mean we should downvote him? What do you want to flag as?

Comment: Yes, maybe as `very low quality` post or for mod's intervention.

Comment: You can’t flag these as low quality because low quality definition as per SE is not bad questions but unreadable, badly formatted posts which can’t be salvaged by edits. For example: cat the fencekew is not blacks povee jump. This doesn’t make sense and hence to be flagged as low quality.

Comment: What can a mod do? Mod can’t take action against a post in scope of site

Comment: Well, If the post is in-scope, not low quality then I see no reason to ban or ask the user to refrain from asking questions, irrespective of whether the user already knows or not.