# How can slow down the rate of posting questions?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions

Does anybody do vetting on this site?  The frequency of posting questions is very high, I bet, compared to the other SE sites. What do the metrics say? I notice too many questions being asked without research, etc.

How can HSE slow down the rate of questions made?

Comment: More questions the better but not in this manner too .. here users posting trivial questions in bulk

Comment: Related -- https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2289/4732

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the more questions the better, I think, because more questions = more knowledge shared and accumulated. The issue is that lots of those questions are low-quality.

---

> The frequency of posting questions is very high [...] compared to the other SE sites.

Hinduism.SE has an average of 5 questions a day, which is about the middle of the pack when it comes to the average QPD across the network; the QPD has remained pretty much the same over the past few years. (30-40 questions a week)

> Too many questions asked without research

You're right, that is an issue. I don't think the problem is the number of questions, it's what the quality of them. There *are* a bunch of short questions here that don't display much research, and even worse, don't display much effort.

---

There are a couple of things that can be done by regular users when encountering a poor, low-quality question:

- Leave a comment for the poster and ask them what research they did.
- Leave a comment for the poster and tell them to clarify, expand, or add details to the question.
- Downvote the question. (And perhaps leave a comment explaining why you downvoted.) [Requires 125 rep]
- Vote to close the question. (Use a custom-close reason: `I'm voting to close this question because it's easily answerable by looking it up`) [Requires 500 rep]
- Write good questions yourself- this might motivate other users to do the same.

---

> How can HSE slow down the rate of questions made?

More serious action can be taken by mods if they think it prudent: A mod can temporarily [suspend](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125268/my-account-has-been-temporarily-suspended-what-does-that-mean) the user for low-quality contributions. This will make it so that the user can't ask, answer, or do anything at all for a set period of time.

There is also an automatic program that, without suspending the user, [does not allow them to ask questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th). It kicks in when the user has contributed several deleted, closed, or downvoted questions, and can only be repealed when the user fixes their behavior.

---

But again, I think the problem isn't with the amount of questions, it's with the quality of them.